# PHP: call a function from another function (out of scope?)

Tags: php, oop, function, scope, nusoap

I'm having a problem creating webservices through nuSOAP (although i believe my problem has nothing to do with it)

What i'm trying to do:

```
function loadActiveItems() {
    $list = Item::loadActive();
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($list as $val){
        //two tests to check if i really have an object and if the toDTO method is callable
        echo var_dump($val);
        echo is_callable(array($val, 'toDTO'));
        array_push($ret, $val->toDTO());
    }
    unset($val);
    return $ret;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function toDTO() on a non-object
```

and both `var_dump($val)` and `is_callable` are returning the expected (the object and true, respectively) from what i've been seeing online, it appears i have a out of scope problem... but for some reason i don't seem to get my head around it :P

Thanks in advance

EDIT: well just check that apparently i don't understand is_callable either because i always get 1 as the result...
EDIT2: i'm using php-activerecord if that helps in any way

Comment: You should not echo the result of var_dump(). Could you post the result of the var_dump?

Comment: maybe try `foreach($list as &$val) { ... }`

Comment: @Florent
`object(Item)[25]
  public 'errors' => null
  private 'attributes' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 1
      'itemtype_id' => int 1
      'parent_id' => null
      'name' => string 'item1' (length=5)
      'active' => int 1
  private '__dirty' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '__readonly' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
  private '__relationships' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '__new_record' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
`

Comment: @Greg nope... it ain't static =(
    public function toDTO(){
        require_once 'DTO/ItemDTO.php';
        return new ItemDTO($this->id,  $this->name, null,  $this->itemtype->name, $this->parent->toDTO());
    }

Comment: @TomIngram didn't work either =/ Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i figured out the problem... thanks for all the help!
I was calling toDTO of another object inside toDTO... problem was that object could be a null!
So a simple if(object==null) solved the problem!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`toDTO()` may be undefined in your class `Item`.

Another reason may be that the method isn't public or as @Grep said` static.

Comment: `    public function toDTO(){
        require_once 'DTO/ItemDTO.php';
        return new ItemDTO($this->id,  $this->name, null,  $this->itemtype->name, $this->parent->toDTO());
    }`

Unfortunately no =/

Comment: What is the result of get_class_methods($val) ?

Comment: well, a huge array :P but `12 => string 'toDTO' (length=5)` is there

Comment: My question may be stupid but, are you sure that all $val aren't null?

Comment: just checked as Mihau Stancu suggested and there aren't any nulls =/

Answer (score 0):

This error never happens on an object that defines the method but it is static or protected/private:

```
Call to a member function toDTO() on a non-object
```

That error only happens if `$val` is not an object. Usually a NULL, FALSE or other scalar.

It's usually a FALSE when the object came for a `db_fetch()` function but the fetch or the query before it failed.

It's usually a NULL when you have an array that may have NULLs in it.

`var_dump($list)`  and see what's in there and if there are any NULLs. Also change your foreach to have a $key and `var_dump($key)` as well to see which key is dumped last before the error is issued.

Comment: the list doesn't have any NULL values and the error occurs on the first item ($key = 0) =/

Comment: What's the value on that key?

Comment: `object(Item)[25]
  public 'errors' => null
  private 'attributes' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 1
      'itemtype_id' => int 1
      'parent_id' => null
      'name' => string 'item1' (length=5)
      'active' => int 1
  private '__dirty' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '__readonly' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
  private '__relationships' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '__new_record' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false`

Comment: Print a [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for the error. Maybe the error is not comming from that object itself but from a function call in the stack.

Comment: well, i'm not really an expert in php so i tried to read the debug_backtrace (which is huge XD) i saw no reference to the $val variable, and according to what i've found i should have, right?

Comment: well, anyway i also used debug_print_backtrace which is a lil bit less overwhelming :P i got this:
>#0 loadActiveItems() #1 call_user_func_array(loadActiveItems, Array ()) called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\ActiveRecordTest\lib\nuSoap\nusoap.php:4089] #2 nusoap_server->invoke_method() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\ActiveRecordTest\lib\nuSoap\nusoap.php:3718] #3 nusoap_server->service() called at [C:\xampp\htdocs\ActiveRecordTest\WebServices\WebService.php:88]

Comment: Ah yes, i remember now, if you use debug_print_backtrace or debug_backtrace it'll print the current scope backtrace. We need the backtrace of the function that caused the error.

Comment: Use this `function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");` it makes all your errors behave like exceptions and shows you the error stack trace.

Comment: sorry i took so long... well i just tried to do that and i get no difference in the output... (tried it with this sample [errorexception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) to check if it has anything to do with my config). I probably should have said i've got xdebug turned on but i can't create breakpoint due to the fact that i'm accessing the web service... but i still got the error message with the call stack

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function toDTO() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ActiveRecordTest\Model\Item.php on line 163 Call Stack
    # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0007 359840 {main}( ) ..\WebService.php:0 2 0.0275 4510048 nusoap_server->service( ) ..\WebService.php:89 3 0.0289 4525680 nusoap_server->invoke_method( ) ..\nusoap.php:3718 4 0.0292 4529848 call_user_func_array ( ) ..\nusoap.php:4089 5 0.0292 4529864 loadActiveItems( ) ..\nusoap.php:4089 6 0.0554 4997640 Item->toDTO( ) ..\WebService.php:31

this is the output i get